# Best method of particle simulation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm about to create a particle simulator in Objective-C on the Mac, using Core Graphics for rendering. I've calculated that Core Graphics is capable of rendering about 1.8*10^6 1x1 colored pixels per second to a view using CGContextFillRect, which works out to about 250,000 1x1 particles per frame being rendered to the screen, for the FPS to remain at 60.

A limit of 250,000 particles isn't that great - I'd like that number to be much higher. What is the most efficient way to render this many 1x1 coloured pixels to a view?
Is there a way to better utilise the GPU?

This is the code I have been using:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    CGContextRef ctx = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CFTimeInterval t1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    CGRect point = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
        CGContextFillRect (ctx, point);
    }

    NSLog(@"%.10f", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - t1);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `CAEmitterLayer` and OpenGL ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenGL, but I know that Core Graphics utilises it so I was hoping that I'd be able to achieve similar performance without learning how to use OpenGL. CAEmitterLayer looks hopeful, I'll do some research on it - thanks.